# Undefined variable:users.....Variable conflict when using a resource controller index and store method in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller, resources, undefined-variable

I'm unable to redirect my controller to the same view index.blade.php after store method, it gives an error Undefined Variable :users, while I redirect through index method, it works fine. How do i fix this

This is UserController

```
public function index()
{
    $users = \App\User::all();
    return view('pages.index')->with('users',$users);
}

public function create()
{
    $users = \App\User::all();
    return view('pages.create', compact('users'));
}


public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
    }
    else
    {
        $users = new User();
        $users->first_name = $request->first_name;
        $users->last_name=$request->last_name;
        $users->email=$request->email;

        $users->save();

        return view('pages.index'); 
    }
}
```

index.blade.view

```
          <tbody>
            @foreach($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <td scope="row">{{$user->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->first_name.' '.$user->last_name}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
          </tbody>
```

Comment: You're not passing `$users` into the blade on the store method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be redirecting to the index route for that resource which returns the index view instead of returning the view itself:

```
return redirect()->route('pages.index');
```

I am not sure what your route is named or what the URL is, but what ever the route that points to the `index` method on your `UserController` is what you want to redirect to.

Comment: Thank you so much @lagbox i was missing such a stupid thing